# Disable opentracing globally

Tags: java, zipkin, opentracing, jaeger

I am using Jaeger opentracing in an instrumented standalone non-spring java app. Does opentacing/Jaeger expose any config or api or any other mechanism to disable it globally?

Which mechanism are you using to enable/disable opentracing if you are in the same boat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess if you set sampler to 0 in the configuration then no traces will be captured.
https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java#testing

But it's specific to Jaeger.
Otherwise you can use NoopTracer like `Tracer tracer = NoopTracerFactory.create();` [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.opentracing/opentracing-noop/0.31.0)